# Is it bad code to forcibly observe LiveData by saving itself again?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

[image]

I am using nested recyclerview.

In the picture, the `red box` is the `Routine Item (Parent Item)`, and the `blue box` is the `Detail Item (Child Item)` in the Routine Item.

You can add a `parent item` dynamically by clicking the `ADD ROUTINE button`.

Similarly, `child items` can be added dynamically by clicking the `ADD button` of the `parent item`.

As a result, this function works just fine.

But the problem is in the code I wrote.

I use a `ViewModel` to observe and update parent item addition/deletion.

However, it does not observe changes in the detail item within the parent item.

I think it's because `LiveData` only detects additions and deletions to the List.

So I put `_items.value = _items.value` code to make it observable when child items are added and deleted.

This way, I didn't even have to use update code like `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `child adapter`.
In the end it is a success, but I don't know if this is the correct code.

*Let me know if you have additional code you want!*

***In Fragment.kt***

```
class WriteRoutineFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : FragmentWriteRoutineBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var adapter : RoutineAdapter
    private val vm : WriteRoutineViewModel by viewModels { WriteRoutineViewModelFactory() }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentWriteRoutineBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        adapter = RoutineAdapter(::addDetail, ::deleteDetail)
        binding.rv.adapter = this.adapter
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        getTabPageResult()

        // RecyclerView Update
        vm.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { updatedItems ->
            adapter.setItems(updatedItems)
        }
    }

    private fun getTabPageResult() {
        val navController = findNavController()
        navController.currentBackStackEntry?.also { stack ->
            stack.savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("workout")?.observe(
                viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
                    vm.addRoutine(result) // ADD ROUTINE
                    stack.savedStateHandle?.remove<String>("workout")
                }
            )
        }
    }

    private fun addDetail(pos: Int) {
        vm.addDetail(pos)
    }

    private fun deleteDetail(pos: Int) {
        vm.deleteDetail(pos)
    }
}
```

***ViewModel***

```
class WriteRoutineViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _items: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<RoutineModel>> = MutableLiveData(arrayListOf())

    val items: LiveData<ArrayList<RoutineModel>> = _items

    fun addRoutine(workout: String) {
        val item = RoutineModel(workout, "TEST")
        _items.value?.add(item)
//        _items.value = _items.value
    }

    fun addDetail(pos: Int) {
        val detail = RoutineDetailModel("TEST", "TEST")
        _items.value?.get(pos)?.addSubItem(detail) // Changing the parent item's details cannot be observed by LiveData.
        _items.value = _items.value // is this right way?
    }

    fun deleteDetail(pos: Int) {
        if(_items.value?.get(pos)?.getSubItemSize()!! > 1)
            _items.value?.get(pos)?.deleteSubItem() // is this right way?
        else
            _items.value?.removeAt(pos)
        _items.value = _items.value // is this right way?

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard practice when using a LiveData with a mutable List type. The code looks like a smell, but it is so common that I think it's acceptable and people who understand LiveData will understand what your code is doing.

However, I much prefer using read-only Lists and immutable model objects if they will be used with RecyclerViews. It's less error prone, and it's necessary if you want to use ListAdapter, which is much better for performance than a regular Adapter. Your current code reloads the entire list into the RecyclerView every time there is any change, which can make your UI feel laggy. ListAdapter analyzes automatically on a background thread your List for which items specifically changed and only rebinds the changed items. But it requires a brand new List instance each time there is a change, so it makes sense to only use read-only Lists if you want to support using it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, your answer is that my code is a general method, but when using `RecyclerView` with a lot of change like my app, it is more recommended to use a class called `ListAdapter`? And I'm not familiar with `ListAdapter`, so I searched and found that there is an easier way to use `DiffUtil` internally?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by easier way. Presumably your model class has something to uniquely identify items in the list, like an ID or unique name. Compare that for `areItemsTheSame`. And if you use a data class for your model class, you can use a simple equality check for `areContentsTheSame`. So it's pretty easy to begin with.

Comment: What I mean is don't use `_items.value = _items.value` to update items, and I wonder if the `ListAdapter` you recommended is more appropriate.

Comment: I think value = value is acceptable but not ideal, whether or not you’re using ListAdapter. The only reason I can think of not to use ListAdapter for any RecyclerView is to save yourself five minutes not having to write your DiffUtil callback, at the expense of runtime performance and having nice animations when inserting or removing items.

Comment: Haha. So what you're saying is that `value = value` isn't wrong, but you should just use a `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Even if you don't use ListAdapter, I think it's just better practice not to publicly expose mutable collections from any class. A publicly exposed mutable collection creates ambiguity, which may not be good for encapsulation. I'm just a solo developer myself, but designing my code as if it's for other team members to work with has helped a lot when I come back to code I haven't looked at in months.

Comment: Imagine you were working on a team where someone else was writing the Fragment that works with your ViewModel. If it exposes a MutableList, then they have to wonder: *Is it OK for me to modify this list, or will there be unwanted side effects? Is it mutable because I need to mutate it in some way that the ViewModel is expecting?* And if they do want to use ListAdapter, they will have to copy the list into another List before passing it to the adapter each time they receive one in the observer, just to be safe.

Comment: I also want to write encapsulation code well, but it's too difficult. Thanks for the good advice anyway.